# Req.body ={} after request post

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

I have this code js:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname+'index.html')
});

app.get('/ins.html', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname+'ins.html')
});

app.post('/ins', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body)
res.redirect('/')
});
```

And this code html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/ins"><p>  <strong>INSERISCI LA TUA CAGATA<br></strong>
                            <br><p>Username&nbsp</p> <input type="text" name="username" required><br>
                            <br><p>Password &nbsp</p> <input type="password" name="password" required><br><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" class="mainBtn" id="submit" value="Inserisci Cagata">
                        <p>
                    </form></h2>
```

When i go to the page, in che console show "{}" and i have not access in the POST variable.
how can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You're using a different encoding than either of your body parsers support.

You're using multipart encoding (`multipart/form-data`) in your form, but your server is expecting JSON (`application/json`) or URL-encoded data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Unless you need to upload files (which require multipart encoding), you should use URL encoding (which is the defualt if `enctype` is not specified). Then the body would be parsed correctly with the `bodyParser.urlencoded()` parser:

```
<form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/ins">
                      <!--   ^--- note the enctype   -->
  <p>
    <strong>INSERISCI LA TUA CAGATA<br></strong>
    <br>
    <p>Username&nbsp</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Password &nbsp</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="mainBtn" id="submit" value="Inserisci Cagata">
  </p>
</form>
```

---

If you *do* need multipart encoding (e.g., if you're uploading files), you can use a multipart body parser (such as [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty#readme) or [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy#readme)). Note that because multipart is a complex encoding, you won't get `req.body` directly, but you have to do some parsing yourself, which is why you should avoid multipart encoding unless you actually need it.